# ¿Por qué se recomienda utilizar el patrón de diseño en un proyecto web o de aplicación?

Tags: patrones-de-diseño

¿Por qué se recomienda utilizar el patrón de diseño en un proyecto web o de aplicación? Sólo uso MVC.

¿Depende del tipo de proyecto para usar un patrón de diseño? ¿O depende del equipo del proyecto?

Comment: Porque son soluciones a problemas comúnes de desarrollo de software que ya están probados, refinados y listos para su uso, los cuales de garantizan calidad en tu diseño, programación y consistencia del mismo

Answer (score 1):

Depende del proyecto es lo que debes de usar y también del nivel de conocimiento, si harás un proyecto que sea complejo y su posterior mantenimiento no lo harás tu o lo vas a delagar los patrones de diseño te pueden servir, por otro lado si el proyecto lo mantendrás tu y no quieres quebrarte la cabeza con patrones, modelos y demás cosas hazlo de la manera tradicional

No siempre lo que dicen los libros o lo que está de moda se acomoda a un proyecto, o a una manera de trabajar

Answer (score 1):

Este [artículo](https://www.genbetadev.com/metodologias-de-programacion/patrones-de-diseno-que-son-y-por-que-debes-usarlos) menciona en palabras simples la importancia de los patrones de diseño, en resumen se puede decir:

> Los patrones de diseño son soluciones para problemas comunes y recurrentes que nos encontramos cuando desarrollamos un software, a pesar que nuestra aplicación sea única, esta tendrá algunas partes comunes con otras aplicaciones como por ejemplo: acceso a datos, creación de objetos con una sola instancia, integraciones con otras aplicaciones, etc. Todo este conjunto de problemas comunes lo podemos solucionar usando los respectivos patrones de diseño, ya que son soluciones probadas que garantizan su funcionamiento.

Answer (score -1):

Encontré esto, hace un tiempo me hice la misma pregunta, la verdad creo que MVC en la actualidad esta algo corto para la cantidad de cosas que requiere un proyecto.

MVC, que ha quedado corto usamos mas de solo 3 elementos para elaborar un sitio web o app exitosa.

https://styde.net/porque-laravel-no-es-mvc-y-tu-deberias-olvidarte-de-mvc/

Comment: No entiendo esto como responde a la pregunta, el OP no está preguntando por MVC, está preguntando la razón por la que se utilizan los patrones de diseño. -1